# looping through object and mapping to a new object in a specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
var objList = [{variantId: "1111", quantity: 2},
{variantId: "222222", quantity: 2},
{variantId: "333333", quantity: 2},
{variantId: "44444", quantity: 1}]
```

I am looking to write a function that takes in a number between 1 and all of the quantities added together ( in this example 7 ) then it will contstruct a new variable that has a total quantity of the input

Items will be added in this order:

1. variantId:1111 - add one of these to the new variable

   variantId:2222 - add one of these ""

   variantId:3333 - add on of these ""

   variantID:4444 - add the only one of these

   variantID:1111 - add the second one of these to new variable

   variantID:2222 - add the second one of these ""

   variantID:3333 - add the second one of these ""

the function will look something like this.

```
function(x){
    var newObj = [];
    var i=0; 
    while(i<x){
     //logic to add the necessary item from the objList
     // really struggling here
     i++;

    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Iterate the array while you still have space in your inventory
2. Check that the current item still has quantity
3. If it doesn't, skip it
4. If it does, decrement the item's quantity and add that item to inventory
5. Return the inventory

Consider this code:

```js
const objList = [{
    variantId: "1111",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    variantId: "222222",
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    variantId: "333333",
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    variantId: "44444",
    quantity: 1
  }
];

function distribute(list, count) {
  // Track our distributed items
  const ret = [];
  // Clone and reverse the array input the array for good measure
  let clone = list
    .map(item => Object.assign({}, item))
    .reverse();
  // Start idx at the "begining"
  let idx = clone.length - 1;
  // Iterate through the inventory while we have room and items
  while (count-- && clone.length) {
    // Push the current item
    ret.push(clone[idx].variantId);
    // Decrement the quantity of items
    clone[idx].quantity--;
    // If we are out of the item, remove it
    if (!clone[idx].quantity) {
      clone.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    // Go to the next item
    idx--;
    // If we reach the "end" of the inventory
    if (!idx) {
      // Go back to the "begining"
      idx = clone.length - 1;
    }
  }
  // Return our parceled items
  return ret;
}

// Test it
console.log(distribute(objList, 5))
```

Comment: thank you sir.  much appreciated! This has been killing me for way too long.